# interrupt handler not registered

Tags: linux-device-driver

I work on dragonboard410c that has the kernel module wcn36xx which registers this way:

```
static const struct of_device_id wcn36xx_of_match[] = {
   { .compatible = "qcom,wcnss-wlan" },
   {}
};
MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(of, wcn36xx_of_match);

static struct platform_driver wcn36xx_driver = {
   .probe      = wcn36xx_probe,
   .remove     = wcn36xx_remove,
   .driver         = {
        .name   = "wcn36xx",
        .of_match_table = wcn36xx_of_match,
   },
};
module_platform_driver(wcn36xx_driver);
```

I want to write my own kernel module that also registers to the same device , I have the code:

```
static const struct of_device_id my_interrupt_of_match[] = {
    { .compatible = "qcom,wcnss-wlan" },
    {}
};
MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(of, lab2_interrupt_of_match);
static struct platform_driver my_driver = {
  .driver= {
    .name = "my_interrupt",
    .of_match_table = my_interrupt_of_match,
  },
  .probe = my_probe,
  .remove = my_remove,
};
```

In the init function I register my driver:

`int err = platform_driver_register(&my_driver);`

But my probe function isn't called.
my module is automatically loaded on boot and the init function is called.

I build my module in a directory external to the kernel code and I put lab2_interrupt.ko on the board in the same directory as wcn36xx.ko:

/lib/modules/4.4.23-linaro-lt-qcom/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/wcn36xx/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that's because the corresponding platform device is already registered with the original `wcn36xx_driver` platform driver.

You should either disable it in your kernel build, or if it is built as a module, you could unload it with `modprobe -r wcn36xx` before loading your `lab2_interrupt` driver, or you could even blacklist it completely to prevent it to be loaded in the first place by adding such a line to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist`

```
blacklist wcn36xx
```

Comment: it works as you wrote. When wcn36xx is not registered, then my module is able to register and it's probe function is called. So is it always possible to register only one driver for a device ?

Comment: @dafnahaktana You can register more than one driver for a device, but only one will "win". It is possible to override the driver for a platform device, then unbind and re-probe. See https://www.redhat.com/archives/libvir-list/2014-April/msg00382.html